# What does the `started` variable do in this code?

Tags: c++, while-loop

Can anyone explain how this code works?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     float longitude;
     float latitude;
     char info[80];
     int started = 0;

     cout << "Data = {";
     while (scanf("%f, %f, %79[^\n]", &latitude, &longitude, info) == 3)
     {
         if(started)
             printf(",\n");
         else
             started = 1;

         printf("{latitude: %f, longitude: %f, info: '%s'}",latitude, longitude, info);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

I dont understand why the `started` variable is used. Why is the value of this variable checked while it is always is set to 0? Can anyone explain this code line by line for me?

Comment: If you can't step through the code "on paper", then I recommend you do it inside a debugger. Step through the code, line by line, in a debugger, and it should be clear to you what it does pretty soon.

Comment: Look at the first time through the `while` loop - what is the value of `started` and which branch of the `if` does it take?  What is printed out?  Now, answer the same questions for the second time through the `while` loop.

Comment: Note that you are mixing `C` style `printf` and `scanf` statements with `C++` style `cout` statements, which is considered poor style by many.

Comment: "it is always is set to 0" - no, it isn't. Read through the code and you'll see where it changes.

Comment: To continue the comment from @NathanS., the C++ `std::cout` stream uses a different buffer than the C `printf` function, and the may not be synchronized. That means if you mix those two types of output your output may be unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf()` returns value `3` making entry into loop,

> while(scanf("%f, %f, %79[^\n]", &latitude, &longitude, info) == 3){

As `started` is declared as `0`, `if` fails making to execute `else` part,

> ```
> if(started)
>       printf(",\n");
> ```

In `else`, started becomes `1`,

> ```
>   else
>      started = 1;
> ```

Prints three values,

> ```
>    printf("{latitude: %f, longitude: %f, info: '%s'}",latitude, longitude, info);
> ```

Here on `started` is `1` printing `\n` until `scanf()` not equals `3` exiting while loop,

> }

Answer (score 3):

> I dont know Why in this code started variable is used?

The `started` variable is used to determine whether this is the first time through the loop.  On the second and later passes, a newline is printed so you don't always print on the same line.

Basically, this code does a loop that reads in 3 values repeatedly (until the user hits enter without typing 3 values), and prints them out.  The first time, no newline is printed, but every other time, a comma + newline will be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Note "started = 1;".

At the first run of the loop, there is no need to add the comma separator. After the assignment, the comma will be added after every argument.